# can I make unlimited day trades with a cash account on tradezero?

Tags: stock-markets

I know That tradezero doesn't have the PDT rule for the margin accounts.
so as I understand if someone has 500$ account he can use them to sell and buy multiple times all the day.

so I was thinking about the cash account . is it also able to do multiple day trades everyday with the same balance or there is a settlement period for that balance after only using it once ?

Comment: It's an offshore broker (not in the U.S.) so they are not subject to the PDT rule.  You need to contact them to find out what services they provide and even more importantly, are they regulated in their locale?